# Is it possible with Chart js or which chart Library can provide this type of chart?

Tags: charts, highcharts, chart.js

I need to create this type of chart, I tried this with chart js but not able to create the exactly same output,

What I am able to create is this [codepen](https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/GRqmbNm)
with these settings,

```
var speedCanvas = document.getElementById("speedChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 0;

var speedData = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],

 datasets: [{
   data: [100, 51, 75, 20, 200, 55, 400],
   fill:false
 }]
};

  var chartOptions = {
   legend: {
    display: false,
   },
  scales: {
   xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      display: false
    }
   }],
yAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  }
  }]
 }
 };

var lineChart = new Chart(speedCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
 data: speedData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

if its not possible with chart JS, can anyone give me idea which JS library gives such charts?

Need to create this type of chart,
[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: The chart in your code pen looks pretty close to the image you posted. The color and shape is a little different. Are you trying to make a chart exactly like that picture, or just the same *type* of chart? What are you trying to accomplish that your current code isn't doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reproduction of your image in the Highcharts. Feel free to customize it more for your needs.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/76frnqc1/

```
  series: [{
    name: '+14%',
    label: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '22px'
      }
    },
    id: 'main',
    data: [
      3.7, 3.3, 3.9, 5.1, 3.5, 3.8, 4.0, 5.0, 6.1, 3.7, 3.3, 6.4,
      6.9, 6.0, 6.8, 4.4, 4.0, 3.8, 5.0, 4.9, 9.2, 9.6, 9.5, 6.3,
      9.5, 10.8, 14.0, 11.5, 10.0, 10.2, 10.3
    ]
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    label: {
      enabled: false
    },
    data: [10.3, 9.4, 8.9, 10.6, 10.5, 11.1,
      10.4, 10.7, 11.3, 10.2, 9.6, 10.2, 11.1, 10.8, 13.0, 12.5, 12.5, 11.3,
      10.1
    ],
    pointStart: 30,
    color: 'gray',
    opacity: 0.6
  }],
```